# Create points along line using CCTV data (irregular interval!)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, linear-referencing

I am trying to create points along a line using CCTV data for our wastewater network using ArcMap 10.3.

There is no field within our pipe to specify upstream/downstream so I have determined the flow of the pipe using the Utility Network Analyst tool.

All measurements within the CCTV Inspections are taken from the upstream manhole.  I would like to have a point created at each of these inspection points.
(A future challenge would be to then include continuity information to create a line rather than point.)

[image: CCTV LOG]

Below is a simplified database diagram.

[image: DATABASE DIAGRAM]

I am unsure how to progress with this ... tracing or linking using the linear referencing tool??

Any suggestions on the next steps I should take?

Comment: Go backward staring with 3rd table, join second to it and 3rd . It will give you route ID. Classic linear referencing task. It is worth to populate 1st\left table with unique string ID, because LR struggling sometimes with numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above I created a view by doing a **full outer join** on the **inspection table** to the **event table** to the **pipe table**.

The points were then created using the [Create Points on Lines tool](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=13c92d8877054b979ac2f69547bd50f1) which allows for distance of points to be created using a specified field.